# Inequality sign in SQL case statement seems to work backwards?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, equality

n00b questioner here. I'm trying to do a query that checks if the most recent activity is within the last 24 hours. I technically can get the result I want, but the inequality in my case statement has to be in the opposite direction as would make sense to me. Here's my query:

```
SELECT sqs.registration_id,
       MAX(sqs.completed_at)           AS 'most recent activity',
       DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS 'one day ago',
       'recent activity?' = CASE
                              WHEN MAX(sqs.completed_at) < 
                                         DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                              THEN 1
                              ELSE 0
                            END
FROM   student_quiz_states sqs
WHERE  sqs.score = 100
GROUP  BY sqs.registration_id
```

Here's an example result:

```
XXXXX   2011-08-02 16:23:53 2011-12-05 00:06:05 0
```

This user did not have activity in the last 24 hours, so the last value returns 0, as I want it to.

However, that doesn't make any sense to me. Shouldn't the case statement return a 1, since the first datetime is much earlier than one day ago? It would make sense to me if my desired results were returned when my when_clause contained a > instead of a <.

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `'recent activity?' = Case ... End`, can you do `Case ... End as 'recent activity?'`   I don't think it'll change the result, but it would be more consistent.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - It will change the result. The `column_alias = expression` syntax is SQL Server specific. In MySQL it will just evaluate the whole thing as a boolean.

Comment: Cheers, @MartinSmith, I guess that I should read `=` as `==` in SQL :-)   It's a few years since I was writing a lot of SQL, and hence I now see `=` as assignment and `==` as equality-test.

Comment: @MartinSmith, you should post an answer. I think a concise answer using `as` instead of `=` is needed. I'd write it myself, but I think somebody such as yourself better deserves the votes. Your answers have helped me understand.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - ruakh's answer does mention it but then goes off on a tangent. Hopefully they will tidy their answer up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your query contains `'recent activity?' = CASE ... END` where it should have `CASE ... END AS 'recent activity?'`. The former is an equality-test rather than an expression with an alias. The reason for the seemingly "inverted" behavior is that, since the `CASE` expression is numeric (it evaluates to `0` or `1`), MySQL performs a numeric equality-test, by converting `'recent activity?'` to 0.0 ([detailed rules here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html)), such that `'recent activity?' = CASE ... END` is *true* when the `CASE` expression gives `0` and *false* when it gives `1`. Since MySQL represents *true* as `1` and *false* as `0`, the end result is the opposite of what you were expecting.

(Note: An earlier version of this answer, while making the same basic point about equality-tests vs. aliases, and about *false* and *true* being `0` and `1`, was vague/confused in other respects, since I didn't recognize that the DBMS was MySQL, and was not aware that some DBMSes allow single-quotes to be used when quoting aliases. So if some of the comments above and below seem a bit strange, it's because they're referring to that version. The current state of the answer is thanks in large part to those comments.)

Comment: SQL Server lets you do single and double quotes for field aliases. Also DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) kinda gives the RDBMS away which is MySQL which also lets you do single quotes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't let you do single-quotes; you've misread the doc you link to. (Double-quotes, yes; actually, basically all SQL engines support double-quotes, so I should have written "ANSI" rather than "Oracle and PostgreSQL's"). I'll take your word for it that SQL Server supports single-quotes, though. Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: Oh, shoot, never mind, sorry. MySQL doesn't let you use single-quotes for identifiers, but according to your doc, "a quoted column alias can be specified using identifier or string quoting characters". As you surely knew. (I feel stupid now!)

Comment: :) by the way if you're ever interested in checking SQL Server syntax you can use Data.SE. Here's an example http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2226/aliases-are-fun

Comment: `'recent activity?' = ...`  does indeed evaluate as a boolean expression in MySQL rather than assign a column alias as is the obvious intent (this is non standard SQL Server syntax) so that is the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ruakh and all. Sorry about DBMS--it's MySQL. I have seen cases where it's 1--basically, any case where `MAX(sqs.completed_at)` is actually greater than `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`, I get a `1`. Changing to `CASE ... END AS 'recent activity?'` does make the inequality work in the correct direction (the direction I intended it to work) that is. The logic of that makes sense to me, but I still don't follow how the `'recent activity?' = Case...` boolean reverses it.

Comment: @khstacking: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html, and search the page for `SELECT 0 = 'x6';`. It turns out that when you use `=` to compare a number to a string, MySQL converts each side to a floating-point number, with `'recent activity?'` being `0.0`.

Comment: (By the way, that's just MySQL. Oracle and PostgreSQL also try to convert the string to a number, but they raise an error when it turns out not to be a very number-y string.)